# Yandex Mapkit Не отображается карта на Xamarin.Android

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Не отображается карта в MapView, т.е. не видно тайлов карты.

Задача, отобразить заданное место на карте маркером.(И нужен ли apiKey для такой задачи? Может дело в нём?)

Содержимое axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/llMap"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="#ef6c00">
    <include
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      layout="@layout/Header"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="static"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Код активности:

```
public class YandexMapActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.YandexMap);

            var map = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.map);
            MapController mMapController = map.MapController;
            mMapController.SetPositionAnimationTo(new GeoPoint(60.113337, 55.151317));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас экран выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу обрадовать, на самом деле нужен ключ. Ключ можно запросить по адресу mapkit@support.yandex.ru с темой письма "Получение ключа для MapKit".

```
<ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="Your api key"
        android:tag="static"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

У меня работает.

Comment: ключи для старой версии уже некоторое время не выдаются, как написала в своём ответе.

Comment: @Reni, мне позавчера выдали ключ, не стоит вводить людей в заблуждение.

Answer (score 0):

Это старая версия MapKit. Она уже много лет заморожена - в ней не добавляется поддержка новых устройств и нельзя получить ключ, необходимый для работы приложения.

Comment: Я использовал версию мап кита 2.5.2 не ужели она настолько старая?
Скрин был сделан со highscreen zera 2012 года.

Comment: да, на гитхабе она отмечена, как  deprecated

Comment: Собрал последнюю библиотеку 2.5.4. Результат тот же карты не видно.

Comment: Не, это всё еще устаревшая версия Map Kit. Вся мажорная версия deprecated.

Comment: Cкиньте, пожалуйста ссылку на новую версию. Поисковики кроме [этого](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/tree/master/yandexmapkit-sample) ничего не находят. Соответственно там 2.5.4. Или как получить последнюю версию?

Comment: к сожалению, пока актуальная версия недоступна, следите за новостями [в Клубе](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi?from=SO). о её выходе точно объявят там

Comment: @MIRILLED месяц назад успешно подключил версию 3.0 yandex map kit, брал здесь [ссылка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit)
и документация [ссылка](https://tech.yandex.ru/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/about-docpage/?from=mapkit)

Comment: @VadimPopov подскажи, как подключил версию 3.0 к Xamarin.Android? Можно ли как-то билдинг лайбрари для Xamarin.Android или nuget package?
У меня целая куча ошибок при компиляции основного проекта

Comment: @atlantis, не юзал xamarin, у меня нативный код, сорь